# restarting app causes NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, swift3, segue

So, I do a segue on fresh install of my app that shows a dialog that asks user to setup some variables that the app needs. Then, for admin users, I have an option to clear the app cache then restart the app so the user can redo the setup if they wanted to.

I restart my app using the code below.

```
func restartApplication () {
       let viewController = SomeViewController()
       let navCtrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

       guard
           let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow,
           let rootViewController = window.rootViewController
           else {
               return
       }

       navCtrl.view.frame = rootViewController.view.frame
       navCtrl.view.layoutIfNeeded()

       UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
           window.rootViewController = navCtrl
       })

   }
```

It works. But when the app reaches `viewDidAppear()` and needs to show my dialog, the app crashes saying

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'Receiver (<AppName.SomeViewController: 0x150dda00>) has no segue with identifier 'showSetup''
```

I think I messed up something for the restart, or I still need to do something for it to work but I don't know what is it.

I'm currently converting my android app to iOS so I want to do everything that I could convert.

This is how I do the segue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSetup", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: What code are you using to show setup in the first place? The issue is probably there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your "relaunched" view controller doesn't come from the storyboard, any references to segues (which relies on the storyboard) will fail.

You need something like:

```
func restartApplication () {
   let navCtrl = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavController")

   guard
       let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow,
       let rootViewController = window.rootViewController
   else {
           return
   }

   navCtrl.view.frame = rootViewController.view.frame
   navCtrl.view.layoutIfNeeded()

   UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
       window.rootViewController = navCtrl
   })

}
```

Comment: so, i need to make my restart code like that, right?

Comment: Yes, it gets the navigation controller from the storyboard, so that the navigation controller can perform segues.

Comment: ohh, i see. i'll try it out

Comment: so i tried it out but it throws `NSInvalidArgumentException` again. doesn't contain a view controller with "SomeViewController"

Comment: ohh. i need to set the `Storyboard ID` of the `ViewController` to make it work. thanks men